# How one defines the expected value of two parameter distribution?

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, expected-value

I have been given two discrete distributions $X$ and $Y$ and values $\mathbb{P}(x_i,y_j)$ for every $i,j$. What is the formula to compute for example $\mathbb{E}(X+Y)$ and $\mathbb{E}(XY)$? My lecture notes do not explain this but I have to count those. In the one parameter case I know the formula is
$\mathbb{E}X=\sum_{x\in\mathbb{R}} xf_X(x)$ and I found from the notes that $f_{XY}(x,y)=\mathbb{P}(X=x\cap Y=y)$ but what is $f_{X+Y}(x,y)$. And I guess that $xf_X(x)$ should be of the form $g(x,y)f_{X+Y}(x,y)$ but what is $g$?

Comment: Hint: one very important idea that you should take away from your statistics course is the _linearity of expectation_ which says in this particular case that $$E[X+Y] = E[X] + E[Y].$$  More generally, $$E\left[\sum_{i} a_i X_i\right] = \sum_i a_iE[X_i]$$

Comment: @DilipSarwate Okay. That gives me $\mathbb{E}(X+Y)$ and $\mathbb{E}(XY)$ can be found by using the identity $(X+Y)^2-(X-Y)^2=4XY$.

Comment: **Another** important idea that you should take away from your course is what is sometimes called the [Law of the Unconscious Statistician](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician) which says, in this instance, that $$E[XY]=\sum_i \sum_j x_i y_j p(x_i, y_j).$$